# Parentheses don't display wth libertine/newtxmath and sansmath

Tags: math-mode, sans-serif, libertine, newtxmath, sansmathfonts

I'm trying to make an environment that uses sans-serif math by default inside the environment, but not outside of it. To do this I'm using the `sansmath` package.

The problem is that, when used with `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[tt=false, type1=true]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath} %works if I remove this
\usepackage{sansmath}


\begin{document}
$(0 + 1) + 2$

\begin{sansmath}
$(3 + 4) + 5$
\end{sansmath}
\end{document}
```

The non-sans part displays fine, but the brackets in the sans section don't show up at all. They do if I remove the `newtxmath` package.

Is there something I can do to get sansmath and libertine working together?

Comment: This sems to be related to the combination of `nextxmath` and `sansmath` but not to `libertine` itself.  (And loading `sansmath` before `newtxmath`, while restoring the missing parentheses and plus signs, of course fails to use sans serif fonts inside the `sansmath` environment.

Comment: It looks like the `sansmath` package is not compatible with the libertine font when used with the `newtxmath` package.
You could use the `sansmathaccent` package, which provides a way to use the libertine math font with the `sansmath` package:

Answer (score 1):

### In Unicode Engines

In `unicode-math`, you can load Libertinus Math as your main math font, and another with `version=sans`.  This cuts the Gordian knot of legacy 8-bit font encodings.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont{kpmath-sans}[version=sans]

\newenvironment{sansmath}{\mathversion{sans}}

\begin{document}
$(0 + 1) + 2$

\begin{sansmath}
$(3 + 4) + 5$
\end{sansmath}
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus Math + KP Sans sample]

### In PDFTeX

You can try patching in the math alphabet from the `newtxsf` package.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\DeclareMathVersion{sans}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sans}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{sans}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{sans}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{sans}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sans}{OML}{ntxsfmi}{m}{it}
% \SetSymbolFont{lettersA}{sans}{U}{ntxsfmia}{m}{it}

\newenvironment{sansmath}{\mathversion{sans}}


\begin{document}
$(0 + 1) + 2$

\begin{sansmath}
$(3 + 4) + 5$
\end{sansmath}
\end{document}
```

[image: Newtx + Libertinus + Newtxsf sample]